# Clear the values on a webform after submitting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a webform with few textboxes and dropdownlists, and a submit button

when the user clicks the submit button im sending the form values to the controller with an ajax call and from controller to model to database

after submitting the form values are still being displayed in the respective textboxes.

i also have a output parameter with my procedure, if the data is successfully submitted then i will get output parameter value as 1 else 0

so based on this output parameter value from the controller i should be able to clear the form values, if the insertion fails the values should be displayed

how to achieve it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CreateUser() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/User/CreateUser")',
            data: { My Data },
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#btnCreate').click(function () {
        CreateUser();
    });
</script>
```

Code:

```
public ActionResult RegisterUser(Users objUser)
{
    //i have done some code here to bind dropdownlists from database etc
    return View(objUser);
}

public ActionResult CreateUser(str Uname)
{
    try
    {
        Users objUser = new Users();
        int Successval = objUser.CreateUser(Uname);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    return RedirectToAction("RegisterUser");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

after you get value `0` then just call below line

`document.getElementById("YOUR_FORM_ID").reset();`

Update

View :

```
<form id="myform">
...
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
function CreateUser() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/User/CreateUser")',
        data: { My Data },

        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            if(data == 0)
              {
               document.getElementById("myform").reset();
              }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: i should add this in my controller or view?

Comment: in view i.e in your javascript after you get response

Comment: i edited my post , can u check it once, how can i send the response from controller to view as im redirecting to another controller after adding the user